# How to get this menu component in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, menu

Is there a menu component like this in java? And how do I use it?

(this is a screenshot of eclipse in the android layout development interface)

[image: Menu Component]
<sub>(source: [vikingindustries.co.za](http://www.vikingindustries.co.za/java/menu.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an ExpandBar, not really menu related but more an expandable composite.  See http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#expandbar for an example creating one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this looks even better than I had in mind.

Comment: Please have a look at my next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253259/how-to-put-an-expandbar-on-a-jpanel

Answer (score 0):

You can easily build this using a `ListView` and customize the list items to look that way.

Comment: I need this menu in a interface, there is no listview in java.

Comment: You originally had it tagged as Android.

Comment: Yes, because the the image I posted comes from eclipse in the android interface development part.