# How to put an expandbar on a JPanel?

Tags: java, eclipse, menu

Is there a way to add a expandbar onto a jframe or jpanel without creating each component with code (using components that is already created).

Here is the code I used: ( http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#expandbar )

```
Display display = new Display ();
Shell shell = new Shell (display);
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
shell.setText("ExpandBar Example");
ExpandBar bar = new ExpandBar (shell, SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

I have tried to add the expandbar to the panel, as well as trying to add the display and the shell to the panel, but does not work.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: You used SWT code as an attempt towards enhancing a Swing component? Really??

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in java, please bare with me. I asked for help because I dont know how these things work.

Comment: I think it very important then that you clarify your question, and then retag it so that you get the right question answered by the experts. So again: does your question relate to coding with the Swing  or the SWT GUI library?

Comment: So it is not possible to add SWT Components to swing, but what if I do it the other way round? Adding the Swing the swing components to JPanel, and then to the SWT window? Thanks

Comment: No. You choose a GUI library and you have to stick with it.

Comment: Okey, thanks for the advice. I recently tried to add the JPanel component to the swt window and it works, however when it resizes some components on the panel go invisible. I understand that these libraries where not meaant to work together, but i realy need a menu that looks similar to the expandbar and also works the same way without redoing the whole project.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is rather incomplete, basing on the example I saw online. I don't know much about `SWT` but `ExpandBar` its not a subclass of `Component` nor `Container` so they can't be added to a `Panel` or `Frame`. 
Found a good example [here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/swt/create-expand-bar-swt.shtml).

I tested it and it works.

The `ExpandBar` documentation is found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/ExpandBar.html)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, what component can I use then to get a menu to function and look like the expandbar? I like how it looks and I need a similar component.

Comment: JComboBox.. I don't exactly know ExpandBar, but they almost look the same